# A greeting with my successor

Tags: word, wordplay, english

> Myself,
>   my last,
>   my first,
>   head off,
>   constant.

What am I?

Hint

> A shibboleth

Comment: Is this a shibboleth that anyone in the world could have a chance to be aware of or is it specific to an area or group that you are in?

Comment: @SohamKonar,  anyone in the world with a knowledge of English. I think most consider that I'm nonstandard, but would be aware of me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Haitch

Myself,

> H (often pronounced 'Haitch', but also 'Aitch', making it a shibboleth)

my last,

> Haitch has H as its last letter

my first,

> Haitch has H as its first letter

head off,

> Aitch, which is how some people say it

constant

> Whether Aitch or Haitch, it's always H

Title (thanks to Stiv for the explanation)

> Put H and I (its successor together) gives 'Hi'.

Comment: Gah! Was literally just writing this up as my revised answer! Well done (and curse you!) +1 :) (PS Apologies for the edit history confusion - got all mixed up when trying to comment!)

Comment: @Stiv, ah, sorry, did not see your latest comment. I +1 your answer too as it is very good.

Comment: Just to finish off your Title remarks, rot13(chggvat vg gbtrgure jvgu vgf 'fhpprffbe' znxrf 'UV', n terrgvat!)... :)

Answer (score 6):

Might you be the place name:

> **MIAMI**?

*Myself,*
*my last,*
*my first,*

> The word '**MI**' represents 'me' or 'myself' in several languages, notably Spanish and Italian. This two-letter string appears at both the end and the start of 'Miami', as both *my last* two letters and *my first* two letters.

*head off,*
*constant.*

> If we remove the first letter (i.e. take its '*head off*') we can parse the remaining letters as '**I AM *i***' - in other words, you get the mathematical *constant*, *i*, which is the 'imaginary' square root of minus one...
>  $$i = \sqrt{-1}$$

The hint:

> Depending on which 'Miami' you inhabit in the United States you might pronounce it very differently - (from Wikipedia) residents of [Miami, Oklahoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami,_Oklahoma) would pronounce it /maɪˈæmə/ (my-AM-ə), whereas those who live in the larger, more renowned Florida city would pronounce it /maɪˈæmi/ (my-AM-ee). This would make it a '[shibboleth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth)' (*a choice of phrasing or even a single word, that distinguishes one group of people from another*).

Comment: Very nice post as usual and somewhat similar wordplay to the answer. Constant means (for now) the first four lines stand for exactly the same answer. When I google Puzzling Stack Exchange <answer> my top result is a comment you made regarding the answer!

Comment: @Tom Interesting - now excuse me while I spend my afternoon googling random words I've previously mentioned in comments... ;-)

Comment: This is when being verbose (apologies) is a disadvantage :P The title's also a clue and only language needed is English. You're well aware of the answer as your comment was about its shibboleth quality (you're spot on with the meaning of this per the clue).

Comment: @Tom Oh, I know what you are now! (And I even found the comment of relevance!)